# Overloading operator for default type in template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

How can i overload operator in template class for every type expect- for example int and char.

```
    Point<char> operator+ (Point<char> const& sec){
        Point<char> tmp(x+2, y+3);
        return tmp;
    }


    Point<int> operator+ (Point<int> const& sec){
        Point<int> tmp(x+sec.x + 1, y+sec.y + 1);
        return tmp;
    }

    Point<T> operator+ (Point<T> const& sec){
        return Point<T>(x+sec.x, y+sec.y);
    }
```

Something like this doesn't work. I can overload for specific types OR for T, but can't combine both.

Comment: use class specify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specialize *outside* the class, like so (minimal example):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Point
{
    Point operator+(Point rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Generic\n";
        return rhs;
    }
};

template<>
Point<char> Point<char>::operator+(Point<char> rhs)
{
    std::cout << "char\n";
    return rhs;
}

template<>
Point<int> Point<int>::operator+(Point<int> rhs)
{
    std::cout << "int\n";
    return rhs;
}


int main()
{
    Point<double> p;
    Point<int> i;
    Point<char> c;

    p + p;
    i + i;
    c + c;
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fb9b6012f61e54d)</kbd>

Comment: Cool, +1, and you don't even need to write `template<>` here.

Comment: @Yola Thanks! You do need, right? It doesn't compile on my side without.

Comment: That depends on version of your compiler.

Comment: @Yola Both gcc/clang need it. Maybe in Visual Studio (which has some funky non-standard extensions and it's not always 100% standard compliant).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement like

```
if(std::is_same<T, int>::value) {...}
else if(std::is_same<T, char>::value) {...}
else {...}
```

Write this inside the code for Point operator+(){}.

I have never implemented this, but I think you can make it work.

I don't know if an operator can be overloaded the way you want, but you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly specialize a member you need its surrounding class template to be explicitly specialized as well. In your case you can use friends:

```
template <class T>
class Point {
public:
    Point(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}

private:
    T x, y;

    friend Point<char> operator+ (Point<char> const& a, Point<char> const& b);
    friend Point<int> operator+ (Point<int> const& a, Point<int> const& b);
    template<class T>
    friend Point<T> operator+ (Point<T> const& a, Point<T> const& b);
    template<class T>
    friend Point<T*> operator+ (Point<T*> const& a, Point<T*> const& b);
};

Point<char> operator+ (Point<char> const& a, Point<char> const& b) {
    std::cout << "overload for char" << std::endl;
    return a;
}


Point<int> operator+ (Point<int> const& a, Point<int> const& b) {
    std::cout << "overload for int" << std::endl;
    return a;
}

template <class T>
Point<T> operator+ (Point<T> const& a, Point<T> const&) {
    std::cout << "overload for other non-pointers type" << std::endl;
    return a;
}

// you can even provide overload for pointers
template <class T>
Point<T*> operator+ (Point<T*> const& a, Point<T*> const&) {
    std::cout << "overload for pointers" << std::endl;
    return a;
}


int main() {

    Point<int> p1(1,1);
    p1 + p1;
    Point<char> p2(1, 1);
    p2 + p2;
    Point<long long> p3(1, 1);
    p3 + p3;

    int i[2];
    Point<int*> p4(i, i+1);
    p4 + p4;

    return 0;
}
```

> overload for int
>   overload for char
>   overload for other non-pointer types
>   overload for pointers